# Refresh hover child element after AJAX triggered by click

Tags: ajax, jquery, hover

Well, I have a span element with a class "outfavori" I'm filling as soon as the dom is loaded with an img element with a class "masterTooltip"... till there, everything is fine, my js "masterTooltip" function at the end works without any issue...

Problem arise when I click on these span element with the class "outfavori", my img element is well replaced after ajax but my "masterTooltip" class is not working anymore on this newly loaded element... Have anybody an idea how to make this new loaded element work again with my "masterTooltip" element?

Thanks in advance for your help...

```
<body>
    <span class="outfavori" relfavori="12">
</span>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.outfavori').html('<img src="images/favori_gris.png" class="masterTooltip" title="Ajouter dans les favoris">');

    $(document).on('click','.outfavori', function(){
        var thisoutfavori = $(this);
        var relfavori = thisoutfavori.attr('relfavori');

        thisoutfavori.html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">');

        var id = 'id=' + relfavori;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax.php?' + id,
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(data) { tip = data; },
            error: function() { tip = 'error'; },
            complete: function() {
                if (tip == '') {
                    thisoutfavori.html('<img src="images/favori_jaune.png" class="masterTooltip" title="Retirer des favoris">');
                    thisoutfavori.removeClass('outfavori').addClass('infavori');
                }
                else {
                    thisoutfavori.html('<span class="error">Error...</span>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('infoTip', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<div class="infoTooltip"></div>')
            .html(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('infoTip'));
        $('.infoTooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20;
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10;
        $('.infoTooltip').css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to use event delegation, so instead of using the short hand method [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover) use event handlers for [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) and [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) functions

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.masterTooltip').on('mouseenter', '.masterTooltip', function(e) {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('infoTip', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<div class="infoTooltip"></div>')
        .html(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
    }).on('mouseleave', '.masterTooltip', function(e) {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('infoTip'));
        $('.infoTooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20;
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10;
        $('.infoTooltip').css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks much Arun!!! actually, I replaced it but used $(document).on('mouseenter', '.masterTooltip', function(e) { instead of $('.masterTooltip').on('mouseenter', '.masterTooltip', function(e) { and it's just perfect!!! thanks again! I blocked on this for few hours and even didn't thought the problem was coming from the mastertooltip function, I thought only about my click function! I'm such a dumm sometimes... but thanks much for your help! :)